# Using Php exec funtion to run a jar file on Azure

Tags: java, php, azure, jar

I will give some background first. I have three files: test.php, test.txt, myJar.jar . Here are the code inside each of them

test.php:

```
<?php
exec("java -cp myJar.jar Hello test.txt", $o);
print_r($o);
?>
```

the actual code that was used to make the myJar.jar file:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Hello
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        FileReader file = new FileReader(args[0]);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
    }
}
```

test.txt:

```
hello hello dinosir
this is a test
testing to the extreme
adding more crap here
and here
```

now I put these files in htdocs and run localhost/test.php using chrome I get:
[image]

Perfect exactly what I wanted. The problem is when I upload these files to github and link it to a website on azure, I go to the website but I only see Array(). I assume its because Azure doesnt have jre to run the "java -cp myJar.jar Hello test.txt" command. Any idea on how I could install/enable jre on azure to make the test.php run the same way as on my localhost

Comment: It could be a case that PHP's `exec()` is disabled by default in your php.ini. It might be an idea to check and see.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked your website configurations? Make sure that Java isn't set to "off" (the default)
[image: Azure portal configuration page for a website]

Comment: what does it mean to have java enabled? If you try to enable java it will ask to choose a web container, lets say we take Tomcat. I dont want my entire website to be java based, I just want the website to have access to a jre to run a few commands. Any ideas on that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make this work in Azure as PHP app is to create `.bat` file. Just like this:

`example.bat` should contain folowing:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%/bin
java -jar %~dp0java-file.jar %*
```

Its important to realize that the only thing you should change is `java-file.jar` and it needs to be wrapped with `%~dp0` and `%*`.

Then execute `.bat` file with `php`:

```
exec("example.bat", $output);
```

Thats it. Works for me.